# Non-associativity in a Haskell AST

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, functional-programming

I have been given the task of writing a parser for which I shall be able to write a composit function  `f(x)(y)`. In the specific parser I am to write, this is unlike functions in most languages a non-associative function. And can best be expressed as `(f(x))(y)` whereas `f(x)(y)` isn't allowed. If I have the following AST what would a non-associative parsing then look like?

As I understand the concept non-associative means that it will be neither left nor right-asosciative. I have had a look at different webpages to understand non-associative operators a bit better, but I am still very confused about the concept.

AST:

```
data Expr =
 |Var String
 |Func Expr [Expr]

type FName = String
```

Would a rightly parsed non-associative expression evaluate as: `(Func (Var "f") [Func (Var "x") [Var "y"]])` or as `(Func (Func (Var "f") [Var "x"]) [Var "y"])` or in an entirely different way?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I would expect that expression to be parsed as `Func (Var "f") [Var "x", Var "y"]`

Comment: It's not `f` that's non-associative, it's the act of function application itself, which is not surprising. (`apply(apply(f, x), y)` and `apply(f, apply(x, y))` would generally *not* be expected to be the same). It's seems odd that the explicit parentheses around `f(x)` are required, as I don't think I've ever seen a language that would need them to disambiguate `f(x)(y)`.

Comment: The first AST you wrote is for f(x(y))

Comment: @DavidYoung hmm... I don't think your suggestion would be the case. I am not sure that I am in fact talking about a composit function when stating `f(x)(y)`, when I, look up composit functions they have a somewhat different structure: `f(g(x))`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition I just assumed that the notation was a bit different, but this is where I am also for 'collective' clarification, and where it might look different in programming and in different languages. I think your suggestion could be written as `f(x,y)`, but isn't that different from  `f(x)(y)` or `f(x(y))`?

Comment: @chepner I am not entirely sure what you mean by when stating that it _isn't_ `f` that is non-associative.  Of your to examples of `apply/2` do you mean that these are respectively left- and right-associative and _therefore_ both (non-)associative? But that this is due to `f`'s associativity. Furthermore I find it confusing if left- and right associativity imples associativy or non associativity. Since I have found sources claiming the latter on Haskell.wiki (https://wiki.haskell.org/wikiupload/3/3d/Functional_Programming_Tutorial_By_Zeeshan_Ali_Ansari.doc) , although I myself find it unlikely

Comment: @chepner I believe the parentheses around `f` is to make the parsing-task easier.

Comment: @user253751 and this would be non-associtaive in your oppinion?

Comment: @Piskator No, it's `apply/2` that's non-associative: compare `add(x, add(y, z)) == add(add(x, y), z)` (always true) vs `apply(apply(f, x), y) == apply(f, apply(x, y))` (which isn't even *defined* if `x` is not callable, regardless of `f`.)

Comment: @Piskator It's difficult to know without knowing the exact requirements you've been given. If the requirements specifically say that application should be non-associative, I would expect the correct answer to be what I've given. Unless they mean that is "non-associative" in the sense that associativity does not hold for application (which is true), rather than that it should be *parsed* in a non-associative way. As I said, it's difficult to know without knowing the exact requirements.

Comment: To summarize: I can think of two very different things they could mean if the instructions say "application is non-associative": The interpretation that @chepner gave and the initial interpretation that I mention. chepner's interpretation is the statement of a true fact about application while my interpretation is affects how you parse applications. The code you have given does not make it clear which one they mean. So, we need more context to answer.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I'm more inclined to agree with chepner, since it would still technically, ultimately, be parsed as left associative, just (potentially) represented in a different form. However, the fact that they are mentioning it at all in the context of parsing (if they are mentioning there?) suggests it might not be that. So I'm still not sure that this is what they mean...

Comment: @chepner , would it here then be correct to say that  `apply(f,x)` would have to return a function in itself (which is the case for a functor I believe?)`. This would have to be the case otherwhise it wouldn't be `callable` on `y`.

Comment: @chepner and @David Young , do we then seem to conclude that it would be `(Func (Func (Var "f") [Var "x"]) [Var "y"])` that probably is expected. 

The task doesn't provide more info than I have already given, based on the example I gave initially.

Comment: Well, that still doesn't answer the questions that are causing my confusion: "Where did you see the word 'non-associative' used in the task description? What *exactly* were they saying in the sentence that used the word 'non-associative'?"

Answer (score 0):

Associativity and parentheses are both used to help the parser unambiguously produce an AST from a given stream of tokens.

As an aside, your `Func` constructor looks more like something to represent a function *definition*. Function application would be represented with another constructor like `Apply Expr Expr`.

As such, in a language which specifies that function application is left-associative, I would expect `f(x)(y)` to look like

```
Apply (Apply (Var "f") (Var "x")) (Var "y")
```

Likewise, if your grammar defines non-associative function application, then `(f(x))(y)` would *still* produce the same AST, because your expression still represents the idea of applying `f` to `x`, *then* applying the result to `y`.

---

Your `Func` rule looks like something that you would use to represent a definition. Continuing with a language that only has variables and function application, your grammar might allow an expression like

```
lambda x: x(y)
```

which would parse as

```
Func (Var "x") (Apply (Var "x") (Var "y"))
```

An example of an expression that defines and immediately applies a function

```
(lambda x: x(y))(z)
```

would then produce an AST

```
(Apply (Func (Var "x") (Apply (Var "x") (Var "y"))) (Var "z"))
```